# real analytic functions on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a real analytic manifold of dimension $k$. Is it then always possible to find real analytic functions $f_1, \dots, f_k \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$, such that they are functionally independent on $M$, (i.e. they are functionally independent in $x$, iff $d_xf_1 \wedge \dots \wedge d_xf_k \neq 0$, iff $F:=(f_1, \dots, f_k) \colon M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is a submersion in $x$.)

If not, is it maybe possible to construct these functions, such that they are functionally independent and real analytic on an open and dense set?

Edit:
I forgot one more property, namely, the function $F:=(f_1, \dots, f_k) \colon M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ should be injective (one the whole of $M$.)

Comment: I don't know what functionally independent means. Are you just trying to produce a real analytic embedding into $\Bbb R^n$? If so, use the real analytic approximation results in Hirsch, differential topology.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm having a Lie group action $G$ (the Adjoint-action) on some $G$-invariant submanifold $W \subset \mathfrak{g}$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the corresponding Lie algebra. Now I'm trying to find functions that are defined everywhere, are $G$-invariant and separate the "principal orbits". Assuming the quotient $W/G$ is a manifold, that means I need to find functions on $W/G$, that are functionally independent in the above sense and such that the function $F \colon W/G=M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ has full rank (almost) everywhere.

Comment: In general this cannot work out with the assumption of injectivity that you have added: By the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, there is not continuous injective function $f:S^2\to\mathbb R^2$.